# Generic type in Web API controller as input

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-web-api

I have this `dto` class:

```
public class VehicleDto<T>
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public T TypeInfo { get; set; }
}
```

and `T` can be one of these classes:

```
public class Machine
{
    public string VId { get; set; }

    public string MachineCategory{ get; set; }
}

public class Motor
{
    public string MId { get; set; }

    public string MotorCategory{ get; set; }
}
```

And this is my action controller:

```
[Route("")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostData(IList<VehicleDto<T>> input)
{

}
```

I want to receive json from clients that type is `VehicleDto` but `T` can be Motor or  Machine I mean different `T` types, I know that `T` can be only one type but how can I have different types in a list. 
One solution is I have different Apis with different types of the input
but I want to know if there is another better way for this.

EDIT:

this is sample input json:

```
[{"Id":"183","TypeInfo":{ "VId":"546","MachineCategory":"MCA"}},{"Id":"123","TypeInfo":{ "MId":"546","MotorCategory":"MTA"}}]
```

Comment: Can you also share sample JSON that you'll be receiving?

Comment: @FaizanRabbani Please see my updated question

Answer (score 0):

If you follow same class structure than you can't deserialize into a single object, as these are two different classes `Motor` and `Machine`,

One way to achieve it by using following class structure:

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public VehicleDto VehicleDto { get; set; }
}

public class VehicleDto
{
    public string VId { get; set; }
    public string MachineCategory { get; set; }
    public string MId { get; set; }
    public string MotorCategory { get; set; }
}
```

And exposing endpoint as:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostData(List<Vehicle>> input)
{

}
```